# How can I use my laptop as a screen?

Tags: screen

I am a complete beginner at this by the way.

Quick explanation of the situation:

- I have the Raspberry Pi2 running Raspbian.
- My laptop is running Windows 8.
- My laptop has no Ethernet port but plenty of USB ports and a Wi-Fi
  connection.
- I do have a screen I can use via HDMI but it isn't convenient as it
  is the family TV.

Is there a way I can connect my Pi to my laptop screen?

Comment: Does your laptop have WiFi? Do you have a WiFi adapter for your Pi? You are going to need sod some matching pair of network adapters for your Pi and laptop (either WiFi or Ethernet). Once you have that sorted you can use SSH to access your Pi. A search of this site or Google will give you the details including how to forward the graphical desktop to your laptop.

Answer (score 4):

Get network connectivity on your pi and follow this tut.

http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/pixming.php

I do X11 forwarding from across the country

Comment: Answers that consist of a link are not helpful.  Consider posting the relevant parts of your link as actual text.  If the link dies tonight, of what use will this answer be?

Comment: Normally, I would agree with you, but as this is such a well written example of all scenarios and best practices, it would only be a method of plagiarism.