# Connect raspberry pi to ubuntu

Tags: pi-2, hdmi, ubuntu

I have recently purchased a Raspberry Pi, my Laptop has HDMI port and I have HDMI cable,how do I connect Raspberry Pi to the Ubuntu PC.

I connected the Raspberry Pi to PC with Ethernet cable, but nothing happened, I researched a lot on Internet but I didn't found my answer. I also tried to connect via ssh but it didn't worked, so I wanted to connect via HDMI cable.

Comment: Connecting via HDMI cable is not going to do anything, you can connect the Pi to a monitor using a HDMI cable. I have found SSH and VNC Viewer to work excellently, there is plenty of good tutorials out there, you just have to look. If you get stuck here is the place to ask.

Comment: As per the answer here already, your laptop's HDMI port is an *output*.  Some other similar questions: [#1](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/647/5538) and [#2](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27935/how-can-i-use-my-laptop-as-a-screen).  What you *can* do is establish either a direct (via ethernet cable or wifi directly from pi to latptop) or indirect (via the same local subnet, presuming you have a router) network connection and use that for (e.g.) ssh and/or VNC.

Comment: However, in order to configure and set that up it is much easier if you connect a screen and keyboard to the pi first.  If you don't have that, Raspbian should allow you to establish an ssh connection using a subnet with an ethernet connection to the router (since it will expect a DHCP server on the other end).

Answer (score 1):

Laptops have got HDMI Output port not Input. You can only connect via ethernet cable Here is the guide: [Raspberry Pi Remote Connections – Without A Network!](https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/)